# How to increase the selectable size of an object for dragging

Tags: c#, unity

I am currently dragging a gameobject like this.

```
   Vector3 screenSpace;
   Vector3 offset;
   void OnMouseDown(){

 //translate the cubes position from the world to Screen Point
 screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
 //calculate any difference between the cubes world position and the mouses Screen position converted to a world point  
 offset = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y, screenSpace.z));
 }

  private float speed = 7.5f;



  void OnMouseDrag(){
     Vector3 curScreenSpace = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y,    screenSpace.z); 
     Vector3 curPosition =  Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenSpace) + offset;
     transform.position = curPosition;
 }
```

Sometimes a user doesn't click directly on an object so is there a way that if a user is between 3-7 pixels off, it still counts as a click and drag? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnMouseDown` method works when Unity casts a ray into the scene from the camera position towards the cursor position when mouse button is pressed. If the ray hits a collider, like the one attached to your object, it will call the `OnMouseDown` method for that object.

This means there's no way to buffer the click radius of the object in relation to its size on screen. The click detection is controlled by the collider of the object. So, if you want to increase the clickable area around the object, without changing the visual size of the object, you need to increase the size of the collider.

---

There is another alternative. You can implement your own click system, and use the [`SphereCast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) method instead of the build in ray cast that Unity uses behind the scene. The sphere cast is similar to a ray cast except it is larger than a ray. Any object inside the sphere's cast radius will be returned as a hit object. I created a video course for Unity, and the [ray casting video](http://www.lynda.com/Unity-3D-tutorials/Ray-casting/160270/177263-4.html?utm_medium=ldc-partner&utm_source=SSPRC&utm_content=524&utm_campaign=CD15496&bid=524&subID1=seray&aid=CD15496) is one of the free videos to watch.

[image]

That'll give you an idea how the casting works. The Mouse Input video also covers casting a ray from the camera into the world.

Comment: Thanks I decided to go with the easier option and just increase the size of my collider